# Rails mysql can't connect using password yes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I install some old app build in Rails 4.0.0 and ruby 1.9.3 gems. Everything goes ok but when I go to rails console and try for example wrote : User, to get database table it give me error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

What is interesting, when I do:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

It says that database was stopped but app still working :)

Can somebody tell what is going on?

Comment: can you connect from mysql client with this parameter - # mysql -h localhost -u root -p   - if not root is not allowed to login from localhost. change your grants

Comment: Yes, I can login to mysql like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - if the database tells you it's stopped, and your app is still working I can think of 3 possible causes.

1. The database is still running, and you've been lied to
2. The app does not need a database to respond to the requests you make
3. The app is using a database elsewhere.

The most obvious way I can think of, it to have a look at config/database.yml, there you can see what database your app is connecting to, and the username/password. If it's not the one you've stopped - there's your answer.

If it is the one you've stopped, the try something like:

```
netstat -an | grep -i mysql
```

to see and the some ps -ef and kills (I'm a bit brutal) as required to bring it down.

otherwise, it may not actually using the database to serve the information you want. If information is hard coded in the controllers and view - it'll serve you just fine.

Comment: unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2868095271 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2868104433 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2868097284 /var/run/mysqld/my

Comment: database.yml is ok, I can use app, create new user etc. but I just can't use rails console and for example rake sitemap:create for sitemap gem ... I can also login , use phpmyadmin ...

Comment: OK, perhaps the rails environment is not set? E.g. rails console development

Comment: Wow YES ... I do not set development mode in database.yml ... long break from RoR ;) Thanks :)